# ffmpeg thumbnailer configure/make trouble in CentOS6

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, package, thumbnails

I am using CentOS 6.4 86x64.

What I am planning to do is install ffmpegthumbnailer.

I have downloaded at the link below.
https://code.google.com/p/ffmpegthumbnailer/

The problem is when I extract the tar.gz and command configure,

It alway says like this.

```
checking for FFMPEG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libavutil libavformat libavcodec >= 52.26.0 libswscale) were not met:

No package 'libavutil' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libswscale' found
```

Of course, I already installed ffmpeg 1.2.

```
 /usr/lib64/libswscale.so.0.11.0
/usr/lib64/libswscale.so.0
```

and also have libswscale.so.

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks:D

============I solved one and get another===============

I solved(?) this with what console said.

adjust PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

I find my libavutil.pc and give that path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH, like below.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

then It looks OK, but I got another one.

./configure works nice with suspected message.

```
CONFIGURATION SUMMARY ----
png support          : disabled
jpeg support         : disabled
gio support          : disabled
register thumbnailer : disabled
unittests            : disabled
debug mode           : disabled
```

anyway, configure was OK, and I have make files now.

The problem is when I do make command, it shows error like below.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr//lib/libavformat.a(allformats.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `ff_a64_muxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr//lib/libavformat.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libffmpegthumbnailer.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/guest/Downloads/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/guest/Downloads/ffmpegthumbnailer-2.0.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please, tell me that I have to do solve this:D

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the ffmpeg-devel package?

```
sudo yum install ffmpeg-devel -y
```

Comment: Yeah. I did. Perhaps ffmpegthumnailer is OSX only? - Anyway thanks for get interested in my problem:D